Error while deploying vite project on github pages
The error is: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
my package.json part looks like following:
{
  "homepage": "https://amanpreet8507.github.io/react-portfolio/",
  "name": "react-portfolio",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
} 

and following is my vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/react-portfolio/",
  plugins: [react()],
});

i have trying running npm run build which is also added in my deployment actions

Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider [edit] to add the link of your GitHub repo or the workflow file. It seems not related to Vite
